# Error while fetching elements of an IFrame inside HTA

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, hta, peoplesoft

We are trying to acheive automation of an Intranet site. We are using HTA along with java script for this purpose. Instead of opening the site in browser, we are using an Iframe, withing the HTA itself, for it (Since the browser security settings bars us from doing anything). Eare able to login to the website,however, after every step from then we get this error message, saying **"Unable to get property 'children' of undefined or null reference."** 
below this it also gives a **URL : http://*******.**.***:8888/cs/domainname/cache/PT_HNAV_JS_MIN_1.js**

To be more specific, it is a peoplesoft site. Can someone shed light on how to resolve this ?

Below is the HTML code :

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <HTA:APPLICATION
         APPLICATIONNAME="HTA"
         SYSMENU="YES"
     >

    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">
    <title>HTA</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function Start() {
    var iframePage = document.getElementById('iframeid').contentDocument;
    var userId = iframePage.getElementById("userid");
    var passwd = iframePage.getElementById("pwd");
    var form = iframePage.getElementById("login");
    userId.value='@@';
    passwd.value='@@';
    form.submit();
    }

    </script>
    </head>
     <body> 
    <form class="form" name="form">
        <input class="links" type="button"  value="Project Plan" onclick="Start();" /> 
    </form> 
        <iframe application="no" src="http://****.**.****:8888/psp/sitename/?cmd=login&languageCd=ENG&" width="600" height="600" id="iframeid"> 

    </body> 
    </html>
```

I could find the first occurance of children in the relevant js file is below :

```
this.fakeBCReqWC = false;  
var bchidden = 0; 
if(eBC.childNodes.length == 0)     bchidden=1; 
this.bcScrollUl = ptUtil.id(pthNav.bcScrollId); 
if    (eBC.children[1])
     var clickedURL = eBC.children[1].firstChild.href; 
var nChildren = 0;     
if     (this.bcScrollUl)
     nChildren = this.bcScrollUl.children.length;  
var nIdx = 0;  
if        (this.fakeBCSetN) {
var isBCpath = false; 
var fakechildindex = 0; 
var i = 0; 
while(nIdx <     nChildren) {
     var child = this.bcScrollUl.children[nIdx]; 
if(child.id && child.id.indexOf    ("FAKE") != -1 && child.firstChild &&     child.firstChild.href     == clickedURL) {
     isBCpath = true; fakechildindex = nIdx;  break; }
     nIdx++; }
```

Comment: When the errors occurs, it asks whether i want to continue  to run the script. As soon as i click on either option (yes or no) , i get logged in to the site. That is exactly what i want, minue the error. :-)

Comment: You've still the same problem? Why did you delete your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416105/how-can-i-access-elements-inside-the-iframe-in-an-hta-using-vbs-and-try-to-fill), and now asking basicly the same again?

Comment: Hi teemu, in previous question, i was not able to access the elements. However, after some changes, i was able to. Hence the previous question was not required. This question, points out another error i am getting. Please help me out with this one :-)

Comment: @Teemu can you please help with this, really stuck here :(

Comment: I could, but at first you've to post the correct code snippet. There's no `children` read anywhere in the current code. The error occurs in PT_HNAV_JS_MIN_1.js file, which is probably loaded to the iframe, not to the HTA file you've posted.

Comment: Hi @Teemu , i am not sure from where it picking up PT_HNAV_JS_MIN_1.js . Probably it is used in the homepage , which appears after successfull login. I was ablo to find out that script in my server though. But apologies , the code it too long to provide here in comments or the question. :-(

Comment: Found code for PT_HNAV_JS_MIN_1.js over here : 

https://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/graduate/691/fall16/01/hw/hw2/CMSC_classes_S14/Class%20Search_files/PT_HNAV_JS_MIN_1.js

Comment: Umh... you've to isolate the relevant code (JS and HTML), and add the snippets to your question. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @Teemu , i have added a small snippet from the js file where the said property 'chilfren' is being used for the very first time.  I am not sure if this would help. Let me know in case i can provide any other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing x-ua-compatible to point to IE 11 resolved the issue. Earlier it pointed to IE9.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you did application="no"
you should do application="yes" to enable the iframe and parent hta window to communicate and allow your hta to work with the iframe dom.
however, that is from my experience with HTAs while working with IE6/7 and that was a long time ago

see more at msdn:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(v=vs.85).aspx#Security

Comment: Thanks sagie, i tried keeping Application=yes, and navigable=yes. the Error went away. But, the web page is now opening in complete HTA, instead of IFrame. How toget away with this ? because i need to open it in IFrame and then use another buttons in HTA to control the events in IFrame.