# HTA to get data from webpage to hta textbox

Tags: html, web-scraping, vbscript, hta

Using Hta i want data from web page to hta text Box. Below is the code which i am trying to create but i have no clue how to call data from web page to hta text box.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>My HTML Application</title>
<script language="vbscript">
  urls=("https://www.99acres.com/shri-laxmi-celebration-residency-sector-2b-vasundhara-ghaziabad-npxid-r63907?src=NPSRP&sid=UiB8IFFTIHwgUyB8IzEjICB8IG5vaWRhIzUjIHwgQ1AxMiB8IFkgIzE4I3wgIHwgMTIgfCMzIyAgfCA3ICM1I3wgIHwgMjMgfCM0MyMgIHw=")
    Sub RunLoop()
        window.navigate urls  
    End Sub
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="RunLoop">
Possession:
<input type="text" name="Possession" Value="">
Configurations:
<input type="text" name="Configurations" Value="">
New Booking Base Price:
<input type="text" name="New Booking Base Price" Value="">
</body>
</html>
```

The data which i require from webpage.

[image]

The output which i require in hta.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194448/open-a-website-in-hta-application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461781/error-while-fetching-elements-of-an-iframe-inside-hta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")*, we get the whole webpage and assign it to an invisible/hidden *div* (for simplicity).  Note that this may result to unwanted styling because of the webpage's own global styling.  A better way to do it is to open the webpage on a separate IE.

HTAs default engine is IE7 so we needed to insert *meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9"* in order to support the *getElementsByClassName* functionality because the data that we want to get from 99acres.com was referenced by *class*.

Copy the code below to notepad and save it as xxx.hta:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">
<title>My HTML Application</title>
<script language="javascript">

var url= "https://www.99acres.com/shri-laxmi-celebration-residency-sector-2b-vasundhara-ghaziabad-npxid-r63907?src=NPSRP&sid=UiB8IFFTIHwgUyB8IzEjICB8IG5vaWRhIzUjIHwgQ1AxMiB8IFkgIzE4I3wgIHwgMTIgfCMzIyAgfCA3ICM1I3wgIHwgMjMgfCM0MyMgIHw=";
var xmlHttp = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

function httpGet(theUrl){
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

function RunLoop() {
    var data = httpGet(url);
    document.getElementById("tempdiv").innerHTML = data;
    document.getElementsByName("Possession")[0].value = document.getElementsByClassName("factVal1")[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementsByName("Configurations")[0].value = document.getElementsByClassName("factVal1")[1].innerHTML;
    document.getElementsByName("New Booking Base Price")[0].value = document.getElementsByClassName("factValsecond")[0].innerHTML;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="javascript:RunLoop();">
Possession:
<input type="text" name="Possession" Value="">
Configurations:
<input type="text" name="Configurations" Value="">
New Booking Base Price:
<input type="text" name="New Booking Base Price" Value="">

<div id="tempdiv" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;height:0px">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Kennydelacruz thanks for the reply, Really you are my hero your code is working fine!!!!